# Build fail after updating to Mountain Lion

Tags: ios, osx-mountain-lion, xcode4.4

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "./Scripts/version.py", line 6, in <module>
    from Foundation import NSMutableDictionary   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/Foundation/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    import objc as _objc   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/objc/__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
    from objc._bridgesupport import *   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC/objc/_bridgesupport.py", line 9, in <module>
    import pkg_resources   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 698, in <module>
    class Environment(object):   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 701, in Environment
    def __init__(self, search_path=None, platform=get_supported_platform(), python=PY_MAJOR):   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 96, in get_supported_platform
    plat = get_build_platform(); m = macosVersionString.match(plat)   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 222, in get_build_platform
    plat = get_platform()   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/util.py", line 98, in get_platform   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/sysconfig.py", line 498, in get_config_vars   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/distutils/sysconfig.py", line 407, in _init_posix distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: $MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET mismatch: now "10.7" but "10.8" during configure Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

I'm using python script for version control to TestFlight. While building I get some error. I don't know anything about python. What's the problem here?

- XCode Version: 4.4
- OS: Mountain Lion 10.8
- MacBook PRO mid2009

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be the key part of the message:

> $MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET mismatch: now "10.7" but "10.8" during
>   configure

Whatever toolset you are using was configured under Mountain Lion but is now running under  Lion, and yet you claim the opposite.

You don't specify what toolset you are using, but it looks like you are going to have to set it up again under your new O/S.

Comment: I just use XCode and phyton script. I have reinstalled XCode, but nothing happened.

Comment: Show us the contents of `./Scripts/version.py` then so we can at least try and work out what you are using (as you don't seem to know).

Comment: I have find solution. I just should change env MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.7 python ./Scripts/version.py to 10.8 in Build Phases->Run Script

Answer (score 1):

It's a little wonky, but if you edit your .bash_profile and add:

export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.8

You should be okay.  I had this same problem when trying to run post-review.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, go into your /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/distutils/sysconfig.py

Goto line 408 that says "raise DistutilsPlatformError" and add a '#' to comment out that line of code... This will "unleash the python"

You are basically telling python "don't worry its not 10.7, I know" there could be some crashes as a result but I think otherwise. My very complex python applicaiton now compiles on MacOSX 10.8 with no troubles and it seems to do the job, QA still has to test it though.

I am on MacBookPro 2012 MacOSX 10.8